# Getting info from wordpress wp-admin editor and using it with back end code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been learning wordpress from an online course. The course is giving me lots of information on how to use wordpress back end, even how to manipulate the wp-editor from the back end code.

The proplem I have is that the course doesn't seem to mention, and I'm not sure about, how to get access to the information and layout that is added to a page or post in the wp-admin page/post editor.

So on the course, in the wp-admin page editor, the guy adds a title like "this is my page" and then one single paragraph like "this is a dummy paragraph". He then accesses that with functions like the_title() and the_content() in while loops, and with queries etc.

What I can't figure out is, if someone was using the wp-admin editor to add content, like adding a new paragraph, or adding an image, and they were applying styling to this in the editor, how would I adapt my back end code, css, html and php, to cope with those changes.

So for example, someone adds a new picture in the editor, and styles it to the left of the page. The wordpress function the_content() drags all that in as html, but how would I then style that image from my css file? I'd have to somehow assign the newly created element with a class or an id? I really can't figure it out. I hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards